# "The monster uses either its X or Y {ability/abilities}"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am writing a science fiction short story and would like some clarification. For the following sentence, which is correct: ability or abilities? A brief explanation of why is also appreciated.

> The [monster] uses either its [ability #1 name] or [ability #2 name] **ability/abilities**.

If it helps, the sentence appears in the following dialogue:

"How does the [monster] behave when it is attacked?" Says [character 1].

"The [monster] uses either its [ability #1 name] or [ability #2 name] **ability/abilities**." Replies [character 2].

Comment: I use either my right or my left hand (not hands).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I would expect _its ability to [do something]_ rather than _its [something] ability_ - but without knowing the words you plan to use, it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: In the singular: the monster uses either its olefactory or hearing ability. In the plural: the monster uses its olefactory and hearing abilities.

Comment: Grammatically the construction is the same, so I am suggesting it should be ability, not abilities. I know it was common in gaming to use X ability rather than ability to X, but for a more general audience I agree with Kate's advice.